Using grep in R to find a file name
I am trying to directly download a geographical shapefile from the internet into R. For example, here is the website with the shapefile: https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/alternative_alternatif.cfm?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=lfsa000b21a_e.zip&k=%20%20%20158240&loc=//www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/geo/sip-pis/boundary-limites/files-fichiers/lfsa000b21a_e.zip
I tried this R code that uses grep to locate the correct file extension:
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

url_1 <- "https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/geo/sip-pis/boundary-limites/files-    fichiers/lfsa000b21a_e.zip"

temp_dir <- tempdir()

zip_file <- file.path(temp_dir, "shapefile.zip")
download.file(url_1, destfile = zip_file)

unzip(zip_file, exdir = temp_dir)

all_files <- list.files(temp_dir, full.names = TRUE)

shp_file <- all_files[grep("\\.shp$", all_files)]

But it seems that grep can not correctly locate the shapefile to import into R?
This is preventing me from running the rest of the R code:
file_1 <- st_read(shp_file)

file_1 <- st_transform(file_1, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

file_1$geometry <- st_make_valid(file_1$geometry)

unlink(temp_dir, recursive = TRUE)

Can this be fixed?

Using the answer below, I combined the code into a single chunk:
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(fs)

url_1 <- "https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/geo/sip-pis/boundary-limites/files-fichiers/lfsa000b21a_e.zip"

temp_dir <- tempdir()

zip_file <- file.path(temp_dir, "shapefile.zip")

download.file(url_1, destfile = zip_file)

exdir_ <- tempfile(pattern = "shp_1")

unzip(zip_file, exdir = exdir_, junkpaths = TRUE)

fs::dir_tree(exdir_)

file_1 <- st_read(exdir_)

file_1 <- st_transform(file_1, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
unlink(temp_dir, recursive = TRUE)


try adding recursive = TRUE to list.files

Did you checked what is happening with the files? What results from the unzipped folder? As @rawr says, list.files(..., recursive = TRUE) is the answer.

If you have a directory with just one shp-file, you can point st_read()/ read_sf() to dir instead and do not need to bother with exact shp file name. Though this is somewhat unfortunate example as files in archive are in a sub-dir, but we can flatten resulting dir tree by using unzip(..., junkpaths = TRUE):
library(sf)

zip_file <- "lfsa000b21a_e.zip"

exdir_ <- tempfile(pattern = "shp_1")
unzip(zip_file, exdir = exdir_, junkpaths = TRUE)
fs::dir_tree(exdir_)
#> C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCiIi1J\shp_1504114f3ed
#> ├── lfsa000b21a_e.dbf
#> ├── lfsa000b21a_e.prj
#> ├── lfsa000b21a_e.shp
#> ├── lfsa000b21a_e.shx
#> └── lfsa000b21a_e.xml
read_sf(exdir_)
#> Simple feature collection with 1643 features and 5 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 3689321 ymin: 659305 xmax: 9015751 ymax: 5242009
#> Projected CRS: NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert
#> ...


unzip() invisibly returns extracted filepaths, so assuming that the archive includes a single shp, you could also just grep() those:
file_2 <- 
  unzip(zip_file, exdir = tempfile(pattern = "shp_2")) |> 
  grep("\\.shp$", x = _, value = TRUE) |> 
  read_sf()


Or perhaps only extract paths (unzip(..., list = TRUE) and leave unzipping for sf / GDAL by using GDAL Virtual File Systems:
shp <- 
  unzip(zip_file, list = TRUE)$Name |> 
  grep("\\.shp$", x = _, value = TRUE)

vsi <- paste("/vsizip", zip_file, shp, sep = "/")
vsi
#> [1] "/vsizip/lfsa000b21a_e.zip/lfsa000b21a_e/lfsa000b21a_e.shp"
file_3 <- read_sf(vsi)


This is sf / GDAL specific, vsi in not meant to be a valid & existing file path but VSI spec , i.e. something starting  with /vsizip/c:\users\   would comply  with GDAL doc & examples.

Thanks for the clarification! In that case your approach is indeed the correct one (and the fact that you hadn’t used file.path() actually made me stop and consider that… which, in hindsight, was the correct signal from your code).

thanks so much guys! Can you guys please tell me if I applied your code correctly here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79012273/intersecting-shapefiles-in-r ?
